# How to strech (Add elasticity) an image at runtime by touch in Android

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine, game-physics

I am new to Android Game Development, I am using **Andengine** for the Game Development. I want to `stretch` an image by the touching the image.

Please note I want to just stretch that part of image which is being touched.

Comment: You should post a specific question about what you have tried already, but has not worked as you expected. Have you tried googling for image processing and manipulation techniques?

Comment: Sprite can be scaled in x and/or y dimension. Do it in your onAreaTouched callback. I believe there is similar usage in the AndEngineSamples project, but I don't have it at hand right now, so can not provide link now.

Comment: Yes i have googling but no solution yet,
Itz great help if i found some sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprite can be scaled in x and/or y dimension. Do it in your onAreaTouched callback.. Thats the simple solution of problem, Thanks all for help specially  正宗白布鞋